# on-screen keyboard help

Tags: onscreen-keyboard

I have installed ubuntu 20.04 onto a lenovo miix 2. the pc is predominately a tablet. The on-screen keyboard works as it should and pops up whenever it is needed. Is there a way to add additional keyboard keys like the up,down,left,right keys. I'm finding I need them frequently as well as other keys. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may try Florence Virtual Keyboard that is available in the ubuntu software center. It has arrow keys.
Adding additional keys to the existing virtual keyboard is difficult.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  I can't get florence to install. the install command reports that it can't find it. IS there a special repository for florence?

Comment: sudo apt-get install florence is the terminal command to install Florence. I checked right now and the command is working. Since it is available in Ubuntu repositories, No need to add a separate repo for that. You may select the mutiverse and universe packages in the software selection